# Is it possible to use a different loader in different contexts in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Let's say I want to load JSON and use `file-loader` when loading from HTML, but i want to use `json-loader` when loading JSON in Javascript.

Does Webpack allow me to do this somehow? I've read bunch of docs, but got nowhere.

Comment: How are you importing JSON from html?

Comment: e.g. here when solving this issue https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/558 , you can for example want to load json using `file-loader` from HTML files, but that's just an example, I've also experienced cases where people loaded translations from Transifex as JSON, etc., I'm just wondering whether Webpack can do this, 'no' could eventually also be an answer to this question :)

Answer (score 0):

In your entry point...

```
require('file?name=src/manifest.json!./path/to/manifest.json');
```

In your html...

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/src/manifest.json">
```

Done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I'm looking for an implicit configuration that would automatically load e.g. json using file-loader from html files and json using json-loader from js files.

Comment: What do you mean load json from a html file? Calling `require` within a script tag in an html page? You can't do that. Webpack loads using `require`, which is a Node.js function and doesn't exist in the browser, where script tags will be executed

Comment: I mean sth like `<link rel="manifest" href="./src/manifest.json">`, I'm aware of the underlying `require()` in Webpack, however I was wondering whether Webpack has something to distinguish between this `<link rel="manifest" href="./src/manifest.json">` and this from .js `require('./src/manifest.json')`

Comment: I updated my answer to show you exactly how to do exactly what you want to do. Try  it. It will work. Note that this is using inline loader definitions (`file!`). There is another option in webpack to specify all loader options as filename regexp in `webpack.config`. This his how you solve your exact issue using that alternate webpack syntax. Ultimately, they are the same exact thing...
https://github.com/jvorcak/create-react-app/commit/c0cd5386d885cb24f521a03a260289c6318c0432